# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:

Tags: android, sqlite

Trying to get a query but doesn't seem to work.It gives out this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Gravity (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT club_id FROM Club WHERE club_name like Gravity
```

This is the code:

```
private String getClubCode(String clubName){
        open();
        Cursor mCursor = myDb.rawQuery("SELECT " + Table.Club.ID + " FROM " + Table.Club.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Table.Club.NAME + " like " + clubName , null);
        close();

        return mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Club.ID));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put Extra **'** before and after clubName:

```
Cursor mCursor = myDb.rawQuery("SELECT " + Table.Club.ID + " FROM " + Table.Club.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Table.Club.NAME + " like '"+ clubName + "'" , null);
```

Comment: Even better, you could use a **bound parameter**.